# how to create a countdown timer in flutter for phone number authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am new to flutter. I am having a flutter and firebase authentication system where users will input their phone number and an otp will be sent to them. I then want to implement a functionality whereby there will be a countdown shown for the otp timeout, so that a users can resend an otp again after timeout.

Currently my code is sending otp to users perfectly, what i want to implement is how to show a timer countdown for the otp timeout.

This is my code

LoginScreen.dart

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Phone Auth'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Column(children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Phone Authentication',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 28),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, right: 10, left: 10),
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Phone Number',
                    prefix: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      child: Text('+234'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  maxLength: 10,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  controller: _controller,
                ),
              )
            ]),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: FlatButton(
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => OTPScreen(_controller.text)));
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Next',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

OTP process Screen

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pinput/pin_put/pin_put.dart';

class OTPScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String phoneNumber;

  OTPScreen({@required this.phoneNumber});
  @override
  _OTPScreenState createState() => _OTPScreenState();
}

class _OTPScreenState extends State<OTPScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String _verificationCode;
  final TextEditingController _pinPutController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _pinPutFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final BoxDecoration pinPutDecoration = BoxDecoration(
    color: const Color.fromRGBO(43, 46, 66, 1),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
    border: Border.all(
      color: const Color.fromRGBO(126, 203, 224, 1),
    ),
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldkey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'OTP Verification',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Code is sent to " + widget.phoneNumber,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Color(0xFF818181),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Enter your 6-digit code',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
              child: PinPut(
                fieldsCount: 6,
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.white),
                eachFieldWidth: 40.0,
                eachFieldHeight: 55.0,
                focusNode: _pinPutFocusNode,
                controller: _pinPutController,
                submittedFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
                selectedFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
                followingFieldDecoration: pinPutDecoration,
                pinAnimationType: PinAnimationType.fade,
                onSubmit: (pin) async {
                  try {
                    await FirebaseAuth.instance
                        .signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                            verificationId: _verificationCode, smsCode: pin))
                        .then((value) async {
                      if (value.user != null) {
                        Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
                            (route) => false);
                      }
                    });
                  } catch (e) {
                    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
                    _scaffoldkey.currentState
                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('invalid OTP')));
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        //Check if timeout has elaspsed, if true then enable button for user to click
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Resend Code',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF81C784)),
                      )),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => SetupProfile()));
                    },
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(33),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      'assets/images/forward.png',
                      height: 50,
                      width: 50,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _verifyPhone() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '+234${widget.phoneNumber}',
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          await FirebaseAuth.instance
              .signInWithCredential(credential)
              .then((value) async {
            if (value.user != null) {
              Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()),
                  (route) => false);
            }
          });
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          print(e.message);
        },
        codeSent: (String verficationID, int resendToken) {
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verficationID;
          });
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationID) {
          setState(() {
            _verificationCode = verificationID;
          });
        },
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 120));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
     _verifyPhone();
  }
}
```